# How to call a python script from Perl?

Tags: python, perl

I need to call "/usr/bin/pdf2txt.py" with few arguments from my Perl script. How should i do this ?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you need to capture **STDOUT**:

```
my $ret = `/usr/bin/pdf2txt.py arg1 arg2`;
```

You can easily capture **STDERR** redirecting it to STDOUT:

```
my $ret = `/usr/bin/pdf2txt.py arg1 arg2 2>&1`;
```

If you need to capture the **exit status**, then you can use:

```
my $ret = system("/usr/bin/pdf2txt.py arg1 arg2");
```

Take in mind that both [``` `` ```](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators)  and [`system()`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/system.html) block until the program finishes execution.

If you don't want to wait, or you need to capture both STDOUT/STDERR and exit status, then you should use [IPC::Open3](http://perldoc.perl.org/IPC/Open3.html).

Comment: It's better to use `system '/usr/bin/pdf2txt.py', $arg1, $arg2` as this will avoid problems (and dangerous bugs) with shell interpolation.

Comment: You can capture both **STDOUT** and exit status using backticks using `$?`
For example:
``my $output = `/usr/bin/pdf2txt.py arg1 arg2 2>&1`;``
`my $ret = $?;`

Answer (score 10):

```
my $output = `/usr/bin/pdf2txt.py arg1 arg2`;
```

Comment: make sure the script is executable (chmod +x) and that it has a proper hashbang (e.g. #!/usr/bin/env python).

Answer (score 3):

If you don't need the script output, but you want the return code, use `system()`:

```
...
my $bin = "/usr/bin/pdf2txt.py";
my @args = qw(arg1 arg2 arg3);
my $cmd = "$bin ".join(" ", @args);

system ($cmd) == 0 or die "command was unable to run to completion:\n$cmd\n";
```

Comment: Don't join the `@args`. Use `system $bin, @args;` - that avoids a number of potentially harmful bugs.

Answer (score 0):

IF you want to see output in "real time" and not when script has finished running , Add **-u** after python. example :

> my $ret = system("python **-u** pdf2txt.py arg1 arg2");