# Calling a python script that returns a value from perl

Tags: python, perl

I have a python function as

```
import commands
output=commands.getputput("ls -l")
print output
return output
```

I need to get this return value from python function from my perl script

```
my($command)=`$python_script_path`;
print $command;
```

My problem is that by printing the ouput in python i can get my results on screen but i actually require this output in Perl script as well so I would rather return it. How can I achieve it ?
Also please note I do not want to use inline python. thanks!!

Comment: For you to print it in your perl script, doesn't it already have to exist in your `$command` variable?

Comment: but doesnt the backtick operation do that ? store the command output in that variable ?

Comment: That is what I am saying, the output of the python script you called will be stored in `$command`

Comment: As a side note, the `commands` module is deprecated in favor of `subprocess`.

Comment: but it doent seem to work. I have been wondering why !! i thought i was wrong somewhere

Comment: actually i am using commands.getstatusoutput() which i believe is easier to use than subprocess and since most of the systems are still having older versions of python in my college i thought commands was a better idea. 
thanks though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [commands](http://docs.python.org/2/library/commands.html) module is deprecated since 2.6. Use [subprocess](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html) instead.

```
p = subprocess.Popen(['ls', '-l'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
print p.communicate()[0]
```

Comment: Wrong way. The OP is calling Python from Perl.

Comment: sorry guys but i require commands.getstatusoutput(). Also most of the systems in my college run older python versions.

Answer (score 0):

Return codes are numerical values.

Your best bet is to print the output and capture the output in Perl.

This might help: [How to call a python script from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340479/how-to-call-a-python-script-from-perl)

Comment: thanks...Isnt that what I have done? am i wrong somewhere in the flow ?

Answer (score 0):

You also can open pipe to the Python script right in the file 'open':

```
open PYTHON, "$python_script_path|";
while(<PYTHON>){
 print;
}
close PYTHON;
```