# How can I get a query from web interface, use it in a python code and then read the result in a perl code?

Tags: python, perl, cgi

I am trying to get a query from a web page, fetch some data from twitter API related to that query by python(2.7.6), save/pass the result to a perl code! and then show the output of my perl code on browser!

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: but why dont you just use pure Perl? - Why that Python step? e.g. [Net::Twitter](http://p3rl.org/Net::Twitter)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in short,

You can write a python script that will fetch the data and get it to print it out stdout and capture the stdout in your perl code.

There is a number of way to do so, I will paste you to another answered question which would show you how its done.

[How to call a python script from Perl?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6340479/how-to-call-a-python-script-from-perl)

Comment: If this is what you are looking for, could you kindly accept my answer by clicking on the arrow ? Thanks, Cheers